# Can a Path contain a cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definition

Can a path contain a cycle .i.e is this diagram a valid path

```
a-----b----c----d
 \   /
  \ /
   e
```

According to this definition of path from 'Introduction to Graph Theory by D.B. West' [image]
So, I ordered this as a,b,c,d,e and call it a path which includes all the edges and vertices in the diagram. path ordering : e,a,b,c,d
Is this wrong, it seems so to me, but don't know why?

Comment: The path graph $P_n$ is a tree with two nodes (vertices) of vertex degree $1$, and the other $n-2$ nodes of vertex degree $2$. A path graph is therefore a graph that can be drawn so that all of its vertices and edges lie on a single straight line [ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathGraph.html ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ordering does not satisfy the given definition, since vertices $d$ and $e$ are not adjacent in the graph, but are adjacent in your list. Indeed, no such ordering exists due to the cycle $a \to b \to e \to a$.

Comment: I got the point, I was missing if and only if statement for if